# How to fix error in prefix "data" for element <data>

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, prefix

I was trying to process a group of XML. And one of the XML has this prefix that's the same with its element name `data:data>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data:data>
  <datasets>
    ...
  </datasets>
</data:data>
```

It caused me this error.

> SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The prefix "data" for element "data:data" is not bound.

I've tried including the prefix "data" on "xsl:stylesheet", just like what I did on prefix "mml" but the error still persists.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd"
xmlns:data="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd" exclude-result
prefixes="xlink xs saxon mml ovid oasis ce sb data">
```

Comment: That input sample with the root element `data:data` is not namespace well-formed XML so it is simply the XML parser rejecting it, you don't get far enough to process it with XSLT at all. Strictly speaking the input you have shown is not a namespace well-formed XML document so any XML tools expecting namespace well-formed XML will be no help. You ought to fix the process producing that input to produce it with the appropriate namespace declaration.